# How can I multiply on real time in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have to show every item added to the database in a table.

[image: Screenshot of the form]

When I add numbers to **Cantidad** , it must have to show the **Total** value

This is my code

```js
function chequear() {
  var precio2;;
  var cantidad2;
  var total2;
  precio2 = document.getElementById('precio1').value;
  cantidad2 = document.getElementById('cantidad1').value;
  total2 = precio2 * cantidad2;
  document.getElementById('total1').value = total2;

  setTimeout(chequear, 1000);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td data-value='Shampoo prueba' data-type='text'>Shampoo de prueba</td>

    <td><input type='text' name='precio1' id='precio1' value='3000' style='color: black; background: transparent; border: 0; text-align: center;' readonly></td>

    <td><input type='text' name='cantidad1' id='cantidad1' value='3' placeholder='0' style='color: black;'></td>

    <td><input type='text' name='total1' id='total1' value='0' placeholder='0' style='color: black;'></td>

    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What issues are you facing with your code?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Comment: So, what is your question?

Answer (score 3):

No need for setTimeout

```js
document.getElementById("tb").addEventListener("input",function() {
  var precio2;
  var cantidad2;
  var total2;
  precio2 = document.getElementById('precio1').value;
  cantidad2 = document.getElementById('cantidad1').value;
  total2 = precio2 * cantidad2;
  document.getElementById('total1').value = total2;

});
```

```html
<table id="tb">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td data-value='Shampoo prueba' data-type='text'>Shampoo de prueba</td>

    <td><input type='text' name='precio1' id='precio1' value='3000' style='color: black; background: transparent; border: 0; text-align: center;' readonly></td>

    <td><input type='text' name='cantidad1' id='cantidad1' value='3' placeholder='0' style='color: black;'></td>

    <td><input type='text' name='total1' id='total1' value='0' placeholder='0' style='color: black;'></td>

    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Also no need for ID

```js
document.getElementById("tb").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  const parent = e.target.closest("tr");
  const precio = parent.querySelector('[name=precio]').value;
  const cantidad = parent.querySelector('[name=cantidad]').value;
  const total = precio * cantidad;
  parent.querySelector('[name=total]').value = total;

});
```

```html
<table id="tb">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td data-value='Shampoo prueba' data-type='text'>Shampoo de prueba</td>

    <td><input type='text' name='precio' value='3000' style='color: black; background: transparent; border: 0; text-align: center;' readonly></td>

    <td><input type='text' name='cantidad' value='3' placeholder='0' style='color: black;'></td>

    <td><input type='text' name='total' value='0' placeholder='0' style='color: black;'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td data-value='Shampoo prueba' data-type='text'>Shampoo de prueba</td>

    <td><input type='text' name='precio' value='3000' style='color: black; background: transparent; border: 0; text-align: center;' readonly></td>

    <td><input type='text' name='cantidad' value='3' placeholder='0' style='color: black;'></td>

    <td><input type='text' name='total' value='0' placeholder='0' style='color: black;'></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using any framework, all you need to do is to listen to "input" events on input elements and in the callback to that event update the corresponding element in this case "total"

(A link to input event documentation)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.